# Determine the lengths of the sides of a right triangle

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

The positive real numbers $a,b,c$ are such that $a^2+b^2=c^2$,  $c=b^2/a$ and
$b-a=1$. Determine $a,b,c.$

Comment: Hint:  plug in what you are given.  Plug $b=a+1$ into the second, then the second into the first, and what do you get?

Comment: Yet another textbook artificial question.

Comment: To my knowledge this particular problem has never appeared in any textbook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From
$a^2+b^2=c^2$ , $c=b^2/a$ and $b-a=1$,
$a^2+b^2 = b^4/a^2$,
so
$a^4+a^2b^2 = b^4$.

We could substitute
$b = a+1$
(if we do,
I get 
$a^4-2a^3-5a^2-4a-1=0$,
which I would rather not try to solve),
but instead we will
multiply by $4$
and use
$4x^2-4x+1 = (2x-1)^2$.

$\begin{align}
4a^4 &= 4b^4-4a^2b^2\\
4a^4+a^4 &= 4b^4-4a^2b^2+a^4\\
5a^4&=(2b^2-a^2)^2
\end{align}
$

so, taking the square root with $2b^2-a^2$,

$\begin{align}
a^2\sqrt{5} 
&= 2b^2-a^2\\
a^2(\sqrt{5}+1) 
&= 2b^2\\
a\sqrt{\sqrt{5}+1} 
&= b\sqrt{2}\\
&= (a+1)\sqrt{2}\\
a(\sqrt{\sqrt{5}+1}- \sqrt{2})
&= \sqrt{2}\\
a &= \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{\sqrt{5}+1}-\sqrt{2}}\\
b &=a+1\\
&= \frac{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{\sqrt{5}+1}-\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{\sqrt{5}+1}-\sqrt{2}}\\
&= \frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{5}+1}}{\sqrt{\sqrt{5}+1}-\sqrt{2}}\\
\end{align}
$

To get $c$,
let $u = \sqrt{\sqrt{5}+1}$
and $v = \sqrt{2}$,
so $a = \frac{v}{u-v}$
and
$b = \frac{u}{u-v}$.

The first equation for $c$ is
$c = \frac{b^2}{a}
= \frac{u^2}{(u-v)^2}\frac{u-v}{v}
=\frac{u^2 }{v(u-v)}$
or
$c^2 = \frac{u^4 }{v^2(u-v)^2}$.

The second equation for $c$
is $c^2=a^2+b^2
=\frac{v^2}{(u-v)^2}
+\frac{u^2}{(u-v)^2}
=\frac{u^2+v^2}{(u-v)^2}
$.

For the two expressions for $c^2$ to be equal,
we need
$\frac{u^4 }{v^2(u-v)^2}
=\frac{u^2+v^2}{(u-v)^2}
$
or
$v^2(u^2+v^2) = u^4$.

To check that these are equal:

$\begin{align}
u^2 
&= \sqrt{5}+1\\
u^4 &= 6+2\sqrt{5}\\
v^2 &= 2\\
u^2+v^2 &= \sqrt{5}+3\\
v^2(u^2+v^2) &=2(\sqrt{5}+3)\\
&= 2\sqrt{5}+6\\
\end{align}
$

so the two are equal (whew!).

We see that
$c = \frac{u^2 }{v(u-v)}
= \frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{\sqrt{2}(\sqrt{\sqrt{5}+1}-\sqrt{2})}
= \frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\sqrt{5}+1}-2}
$.

Note: 
If we take the square root with $a^2-2b^2$,
we get

$\begin{align}
a^2\sqrt{5} 
&= a^2-2b^2\\
a^2(1-\sqrt{5}) 
&= 2b^2\\
\end{align}
$

which can not be 
since the left side is negative
and the right side is positive.

Comment: I noticed that also and fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use $b-a=1$ to find an expression for $b$ in terms of $a$ (very easy), then substitute this into $c=\frac{b^2}{a}$  to get $c$ in terms of $a$. now you can write $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ in terms of $a$. Then solve the quadratic to find $a$ and you can get the other terms from the expressions you have already derived. I haven't worked out what the roots of $a$ will be, but only one of them will be positive and give positive values for $b$ and $c$.

You can use this approach whenever you have $n$ equations in $n$ unknowns, although sometimes it can be difficult to see where to start. Here, it is fairly obvious to start with the simplest equation and build up.

Comment: You get a quartic for $a$, not a quadratic.

Comment: Quite right, didn't realize it would be that tricky. Like your solution.

Answer (score 2):

$$a^2+b^2=\frac{b^4}{a^2} \Rightarrow a^4+a^2b^2=b^4 \Rightarrow \frac{a^4}{b^4}+\frac{a^2}{b^2}=1\,.$$

Let $x =\frac{a^2}{b^2}$ then, as $x \geq 0$

$$x^2+x=1 \Rightarrow x=\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2} \,.$$

Thus $$\frac{a}{b}= \sqrt{\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}}$$

This implies that

$$1- \frac{1}{b}=\frac{b-1}{b}= \sqrt{\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}} \Rightarrow b =\frac{1}{1-\sqrt{\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}}} \,.$$

Now all you need is to simplify these expressions....